# How to rename entries whose values fall in certain range?

Tags: r

For example, I am trying to rename all the values 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 from column V26 in the dataset xpriorjail as  "Happy"

This code isn't working for some reason

```
xpriorjail$V26[xpriorjail$V26 >= 10 & xpriorjail$V26 <= 12] <- "Happy"
```

Comment: It runs OK when I set it up. What's the error?

Comment: The OP wants to rename _all the values 10, 11, 12, 13, 14_ but his code snippet only considers 10, 11, and 12: `xpriorjail$V26[xpriorjail$V26 >= 10 & xpriorjail$V26 <= 12]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example using `cut` and an example using `factor`, as mentioned in my comment. I would suggest creating a new column rather than overwriting your existing one so you can easily access the original numeric values if required.

***Sample data***

```
set.seed(1)
V26 <- sample(4, 20, replace = TRUE)
V26
#  [1] 2 2 3 4 1 4 4 3 3 1 1 1 3 2 4 2 3 4 2 4
```

***Option 1: `cut`***

```
V26Cut <- cut(V26, breaks = c(0, 2, 4), 
              labels = c("Happy", "Sad"))
V26Cut
#  [1] Happy Happy Sad   Sad   Happy Sad   Sad   Sad   Sad   Happy Happy
# [12] Happy Sad   Happy Sad   Happy Sad   Sad   Happy Sad  
# Levels: Happy Sad
```

***Option 2: `factor` + `levels`***

```
V26Factor <- factor(V26)
levels(V26Factor) <- list(Happy = as.character(1:2), Sad = as.character(3:4))
V26Factor
#  [1] Happy Happy Sad   Sad   Happy Sad   Sad   Sad   Sad   Happy Happy
# [12] Happy Sad   Happy Sad   Happy Sad   Sad   Happy Sad  
# Levels: Happy Sad
```